# What does copy-reference-file in find ... -exec bash -c ". jenkins-support; copy_reference_file '{}'" \; do?

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins

Can someone explain what the following command does?

```
find /usr/share/jenkins/ref/ -type f -exec bash -c ". /usr/local/bin/jenkins-support; copy_reference_file '{}'" \;
```

In the above example, what would `copy_reference_file` refer to?

Comment: It's just a program name. It will be executed with the found filename as an argument.

Comment: I guess it's part of the [Jenkins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenkins_(software)) software.

Comment: It's very likely a function defined in the `jenkins-support` script.

Comment: BTW, it'd be both more efficient and more secure (against files with malicious names) to write this differently: `-exec bash -c '. /usr/local/bin/jenkins-support; for arg; do copy_reference_file "$arg"; done' _ {} +`

Comment: Consider what happens if you have a file created with `touch $'./\'$(rm -rf $HOME)\'$(rm -rf $HOME)'` (repeated to be sure it activates whether or not literal quotes are added) somewhere inside the directory structure being searched. Having GNU `find` replacing `{}` inside your code passed as an argument to `bash -c` is dangerous. Always, **always** pass filenames as separate arguments, rather than substituting them inside text parsed as code.

Comment: BTW, in general, always make sure a question title describes not just what tools you're using, but what your actual question is about. I've tried to edit to do that here.

Comment: OP: Since this is almost for-sure a busted use case you're troubleshooting, the contents of the question should probably have the set ([what you're trying to do], [what you're expecting to see], [what you're actually getting]) to help your compatriots.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  Actually, I was reading through a shell script and wanted to know what it was doing.  `jenkins-support` is indeed a script and `copy_reference_file` is a function.  This is more advanced scripting than I am experienced with.  What is a good resource to learn about these techniques?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This recursive find does:

- starting in `/usr/share/jenkins/ref/` and in all of its subdirectories:
- for every regular file (that is, files that are not symlinks, directories, devices, etc) found:
- after sourcing the file `/usr/local/bin/jenkins-support` (to set environment variables or otherwise modify the execution environment):
- run the command `copy_reference_file` against each file you found

I'm guessing that this probably copies in prerequisites for a build run before actually running the build.  Google is replete with failures of this command, mostly around Docker and how volumes get mounted when jenkins is running.

As in most things UNIX, any issues are either case (upper/lower), path (where a file is), or permissions.  Any issues you see are probably the latter.

EDIT: As a reference, I've pasted the relevant content of /usr/local/bin/jenkins-support on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/2xJn3e5T).  Looks like it mostly slings around Jenkins components such as plugins.  This exact line appears to come from the [the main Jenkins startup script in the Docker image](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/master/jenkins.sh).

Comment: It's possible if not likely that this command is not an executable binary, but a shell function defined in the `jenkins-support` script -- which is why I modified your answer to be more general rather than potentially implying that `jenkins-support` is only modifying environment variables.

Comment: Fair point.  Been trying to find a ref in the jenkins sources, but it's not been going to well on my phone.  Time to grab the PC.

Comment: BTW, the OP's original code actually has a major security bug -- see my comments on the question. A full explanation of what it does would arguably cover that bug, or at least specify a fix (and describe that it's explaining what the *fixed* version does). :)

Comment: I've seen exactly this line referenced elsewhere; I'd bet it's in the Jenkins source (in which case this would be a PR against Jenkins).  More than likely the OP ran into one of the many Docker<->Jenkins interaction issues and is trying to troubleshoot his automated builds.

Comment: *sigh*. I've long had a prejudice (dating to early Tomcat) that Java developers as a whole can't write secure shell scripts to save their lives (reinforced by a bunch of security bugs in a rather popular open-source SSH-based orchestration tool I did an audit of at my last job -- in code that was *explicitly written* to escape strings to be safe for inclusion in shell command lines). If this is indeed coming from Jenkins upstream, this particular encounter isn't helping to dispel it.

Comment: You should see what gems Windoze devs come up with.  Their only saving grace pre-powershell was that cmd.exe was lobotomized to the point that it was too stupid to be exploited in too many ways.

Comment: Thanks for tracking that down. I'll file a ticket upstream.